# Ito's formula example

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Let us assume that the stock price $S_t$ follows BS model
\begin{equation}dS_t=S_t(\mu(t)dt+\sigma(S_t,t)dB_t).\end{equation}
I want to show that for constant $\mu$ and $\sigma$, the solution to the previous SDE is
$$S_t=S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma B_t},\ \ \ t\in[0,T]$$
for $T>0$. My solution so far:

Let us denote
        $$g(t,x)=e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma x }$$
        and it's partial derivatives are
        $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x)=\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma x },$$
        $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,x)=\sigma e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma x },$$
        $$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(t,x)=\sigma^2 e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma x }.$$
        Setting $X_t=B_t$ and denoting $Y_t=g(t,X_t)$, Ito's formula gives us
        \begin{align*}
   dY_t&=\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,X_t)dt+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,X_t)dX_t+\frac12\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}(t,X_t)(dX_t)^2\\
   &=\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma B_t}dt+\sigma e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma B_t}dB_t+\frac12\sigma^2e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma B_t}dt\\
   &=Y_t\left(\mu dt+\sigma dB_t\right).
   \end{align*}
This should give us that $S_t=g(t,X_t)=e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma B_t }$ but the scalar $S_0$ is missing. Any ideas on how it was lost?

Comment: You have things mixed up. Apparently $Y_t$ and $S_t$ stand for the same thing. Also, the partial derivative of $g$ by $x$ should have a minus sign, no?

Comment: $Y_t$ is simply brought in for the use of Ito's lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set $g(t,x)= S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t-\sigma x }$, since that is the function you want to prove something about.

The factor $S_0$ should just slip through the whole calculation. Edit: Basically you proved just the special case $S_0 = 1$

Second Edit concerning the comment:

Take $h(x,t) = S_0g(x,t)$.

The partial derivatives are $h_\xi(x,t) = S_0g_\xi(x,t)$ where $\xi$ can be $x$, $xx$ or $t$. Take $Z_t = h(t,X_t)$ or $Z_t = S_0Y_t$

\begin{align*}
   dZ_t&=S_0\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,X_t)dt+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,X_t)dX_t+\frac12\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}(t,X_t)(dX_t)^2\right)\\
   &=S_0Y_t\left(\mu dt+\sigma dB_t\right) \\
&= Z_t\left(\mu dt+\sigma dB_t\right)
   \end{align*}

The $Y_0$ or $S_0$ is "absorbed" again by the random variable.

Comment: But then I end up with $dY_t=Y_0Y_t(\mu dt+\sigma dB_t)$, which is not in accordance with the initial assumption.

Comment: I don't think so. I added my calculation. Do you agree?